# Mutating a travelling window in a Rust ndarray

Tags: multidimensional-array, rust

I am attempting to implement one iteration of [Conway's Game of Life](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conway%27s_Game_of_Life#Rules) in Rust using the [ndarray](https://github.com/bluss/rust-ndarray) library.

I thought a 3x3 window looping over the array would be a simple way to count the living neighbours, however I am having trouble doing the actual update.

The array signifies life with `#` and the absence of life with :

```
let mut world = Array2::<String>::from_elem((10, 10), " ".to_string());
for mut window in world.windows((3, 3)) {
    let count_all  = window.fold(0, |count, cell| if cell == "#" { count + 1 } else { count });
    let count_neighbours = count_all - if window[(1, 1)] == "#" { 1 } else { 0 };
    match count_neighbours {
        0 | 1   => window[(1, 1)] = " ".to_string(), // Under-population
        2       => {},                               // Live if alive
        3       => window[(1, 1)] = "#".to_string(), // Re-produce
        _       => window[(1, 1)] = " ".to_string(), // Over-population
    }
}
```

This code does not compile! The error is within the `match` block with "error: cannot borrow as mutable" and "error: cannot assign to immutable index". I attempted `for &mut window...` but the library does not implement this(?)

I'm relatively new to Rust and I believe this *may* be an issue with the implementation of windows by the library. However, I'm not sure and I don't know if there perhaps some variation/fix that allows me to continue with this approach. Do I need to scrap this approach entirely? I'm not sure what the best approach would be here.

Any other suggestions or improvements to the code would be greatly appreciated.

(This code doesn't implement proper rules as I am mutating as I loop and I am ignoring the outer edge, however that is okay in this case. Also, any variations which do these things are also okay - the details are not important.)

Comment: Funny enough, your approach of Conway's game of life may not work properly, since you are progressively mutating the grid while counting neighbour cells. The game assumes that all neighbour checks are performed at once in each frame, before any cells die or reproduce. Therefore, replicating the game's state into a second object is devoid of the issue in your question, and would just work better in general.

Comment: I do say that I don't implement the proper rules and that that is okay - the main reason was that I struggled to produce a version that worked with a copy because I wasn't able to do a alternative loop to "windows"!

Comment: That sounds like a good challenge for you to look into.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your general approach using `ndarray` and `windows` is ok, but the problem is that the values that you get from the `windows` iterator will always be immutable. You can work around that by wrapping the values in `Cell` or `RefCell`, which gives you interior mutability. That is, they wrap a value as if it was immutable, but provide an API to let you mutate it anyway.

Here is your code, fairly brutally adapted to use `RefCell`:

```
use ndarray::Array2;
use std::cell::RefCell;

fn main() {
    // creating variables for convenience, so they can be &-referenced
    let alive = String::from("#");
    let dead = String::from(" ");

    let world = Array2::<String>::from_elem((10, 10), " ".to_string());
    let world = world.map(RefCell::new);

    for mut window in world.windows((3, 3)) {
        let count_all  = window.fold(0, |count, cell| if *cell.borrow() == &alive { count + 1 } else { count });
        let count_neighbours = count_all - if *window[(1, 1)].borrow() == &alive { 1 } else { 0 };
        match count_neighbours {
            0 | 1   => *window[(1, 1)].borrow_mut() = &dead,  // Under-population
            2       => {},                                    // Live if alive
            3       => *window[(1, 1)].borrow_mut() = &alive, // Re-produce
            _       => *window[(1, 1)].borrow_mut() = &alive, // Over-population
        }
    }
}
```

What I've done above is really just to get your code working, pretty much as-is. But, as E_net4 pointed out, your solution has a major bug because it is mutating as it reads. Also, in terms of best-practices, your usage of `String` isn't ideal. An `enum` is much better because it's smaller, can be stack-allocated and better captures the invariants of your model. With an `enum` you would derive `Copy` as below, which would let you use a `Cell` instead of `RefCell`, which is likely to be better performance because it copies the data, instead of having to count references.

```
#[derive(Debug, PartialEq, Clone, Copy)]
enum CellState {
    Alive,
    Dead
}
```

Comment: Correction: there is no runtime overhead using `Cell` (because it just copies the underlying value) however there is a slight runtime overhead using `RefCell` (it's reference counted like a read-write mutex).